# How to get navigation bar on ViewBased Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to add navigation bar on to ViewBased application [templet]

Comment: i tried for its not added its showing my white screen

Comment: How have you tried then?

Comment: created Viewbased Templet and added UINavigationBar to appdelegate class and set property allocated in implementation added to self.window

Answer (score 0):

The following code will present a new navigation controller.

```
MyViewController *v = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *t = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v];
[self presentModalViewController:t animated:true]; 
[t release];
[v release];
```

Otherwise, u can add the navigation bar to the nib file associated with the viewcontroller directly.

Comment: He's talking about a ViewBased-application, not a NavigationBased-app :).

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate.m`-file, add this under `applicationDidFinishLaunching` (or something like that).

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
[window addSubview:navigationBar];
```